# Laravel - supervisors can view their department data only

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i want to create statement for supervisor only can view their own department all data.

My Controller

```
public function index(User $user)
{
    if(auth()->user()->role == 'Admin')
    {
        $form = Form::all();
    }
    elseif(auth()->user()->positions == 'Supervisor') 
    {
        $form = Form::where('dept_id', \Auth::user()->id)->get();
    }
    else
    {
        $form = Form::where('user_id', \Auth::user()->id)->get();
    }

    return view('form.index', ['list_form' => $form]);
}
```

Form Table DB

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('form001', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users');
        $table->foreignId('dept_id')->constrained('users');
        $table->string('nama');
        $table->string('komputer');
        $table->string('type');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

User Table Form

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('dept');
        $table->string('positions');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Am i in the right direction?Or can someone direct me in the right direction?

Comment: At a first glance it might look correct, did you try it? Does it work? [EDIT: `auth()->user()->positions` shouldn't `positions` be `->role`? And if you have `public function index(User $user)` there is no need to  `auth()->user()->` you can just `$user->` (this obviously only if you pass the user during the call)]

Comment: positions == supervisor can view own data only, cant see their department yet (is my database table relations correct ? )

 i change my controller auth()->user()-> to where('role_id, $user->id)->get();`

Comment: `where('role_id, $user->id)->get();` It depends if role_id points to users table, I don't know if that's a design choice but if it means the same as `where('user_id, $user->id)->get();` then it's correct. There are some problems with relations, maybe i'll cover them in another comment

Comment: Here are the docs on migrations: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations

As you can see from there laravel follows some naming conventions and pointing `dept_id` to `users` table might not be very intuitive for this framework. I would suggest declaring the old way: `$table->unsignedBigInteger('dept_id')` and `$table->foreign('dept_id')->references('dept')->on('users')->blablabla...`. Moreover you declared dept as a string, but the column pointing to it is an integer: that relation cannot work. I'd suggest using dept (in users) as a foreign key (unsignedBigInteger or foreignId) to dept table